# wget how to send HTTP response to STD OUT or File when using post-file

Tags: http, wget, put

I've been looking for some hours and I cannot find a solution for this.

I use wget to upload (HTTP PUT) a file to a server in this way:

```
/usr/bin/wget '--header=Content-Type: application/xml' '--post-file=/tmp/cda_initialParentApplication.xml' 'https://myserver.net:8443/remote/rest/v1/application?force=true' '--no-check-certificate' '--server-response' '--output-file=/wget_put.txt'
```

In general it works fine. The only thing is once the upload finishes, a new file containing the response is created:

`...
...
Saving to: ?application?force=true?
0K                                                       100% 8.81M=0s`

`$more application\?force\=true
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><results><result updated="true" targetName="myApp"/></results>`

Is there a way to avoid this response message to be created in that file?? Ideally send that response to STD OUT or to a specific file??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just redirect the output do /dev/null (and enable quiet) like this:

```
wget --quiet -O /dev/null http://...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. Yes, i agree, the best way will be to redirect the output somewhere else like /dev/null.